# Выборка участка данных из БД

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

Есть проект использующий C# .NET, Entity Framework. Так же есть таблица с большим количеством полей. Использую Linq to entity не получается выбрать только участок данных из этой таблицы. Пытаюсь так:

```
...
var query = context.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking();
...
return query.Skip(skipCount).Take(count).ToList();
```

Смысл последней стоки в том, что нужно пропустить определенное кол-во записей, и выбрать следующие count записей после пропущенных. Но такой подход не работает, т.к Skip применяется только для отсортированного набора. Есть ли какие нибудь варианты, как можно решить такую задачу? Если вернуть query.ToList(), а потом для него выполнять skip и take, то он пытается получить все записи из таблицы, что занимает ~ 10 минут, потом для полученной коллекции делает skip и потом для новой коллекции делает take.

PS: испольузется genericRepositores, ключ сортировки не определен изначально.

Comment: Ну так отсортируйте!

Comment: Generic repositories, по какому ключу делать сортировку не понятно.

Comment: @QuaternioNoir не используйте Generic repositories, это кака. Они не решают никаких проблем, только создают видимость работы и проблемы.

Comment: Как вы представляете взятие определенного числа данных без сортировки?

Comment: Можно разных вариантов напридумывать, что бы найти певичный ключ, навешать атрибутов, добавить интерфейс с кючом, можно вытащить из EF, вот пример, может пригодиться http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42645667/how-can-i-get-the-primary-key-for-the-dbset